# Failure in python installation

Tags: python, macos, gentoo

I'm trying to install Gentoo Prefix on an iMac (OS-X 10.8.2). During the installation, Python 2.7.3 installation fails. Here is the traceback:

```
...
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libpython2.7.a(pymath.o) has no symbols
ranlib libpython2.7.a
ranlib: file: libpython2.7.a(pymath.o) has no symbols
gcc -L/Users/me/Gentoo/tmp/usr/lib  -o python.exe \
            Modules/python.o \
            libpython2.7.a -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
  File "/Users/me/Gentoo/tmp/var/tmp/python-2.7.3/Python-2.7.3/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 37, in <module>
    class build_ext (Command):
  File "/Users/me/Gentoo/tmp/var/tmp/python-2.7.3/Python-2.7.3/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 67, in build_ext
    "(default: %s)" % get_platform()),
  File "/Users/me/Gentoo/tmp/var/tmp/python-2.7.3/Python-2.7.3/Lib/distutils/util.py", line 103, in get_platform
    cfgvars = get_config_vars()
  File "/Users/me/Gentoo/tmp/var/tmp/python-2.7.3/Python-2.7.3/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 568, in get_config_vars
    flags = _config_vars[key]
KeyError: 'CXXFLAGS'
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1
```

I can only deduce, perhaps wrongly, that `CXXFLAGS` was not present in a dictionary `_config_vars` when it was expected. But why? Any ideas anyone?  I imagine this is Prefix-specific, but perhaps not.

Comment: Is this during bootstrapping, or later? What command did you run to get this error?

Comment: Do you have Xcode and its Command Line Tools (as one of the first big green Notes in the docs tells you that you need)? Also, do you have anything like MacPorts, Homebrew, etc. installed, or any non-standard env variables (as the docs explicitly tell you that you can't)?

Comment: yes, during bootstrapping - running ./bootstrap-prefix.txt.  Yes I have the tools. No I don't have any other things. This is a fresh install of OSX

Comment: Note that the installation has fetched and built 20 other modules before starting on Python.

Comment: Does the traceback show which extension it was building at the time?  The only place I see `CXXFLAGS` referenced in the source is in the `libffi` build included with the `ctypes` module.

Comment: I think you're more likely to get an answer on the gentoo-alt list. Especially since the FAQ for prefix starts off by begging for more user involvement, and then repeats that plea multiple times. Also, since there's nothing directly programming-related in your question, another site like superuser would probably fit better than SO.

Comment: @NedDeily as far as I can see it has just built the core python module and created a python.exe (odd name on a Mac). The failure then comes from sysconfig.py (where there are refs to CXXFLAGS).

Comment: @abarnert yes I posted on the gentoo-alt list several days back, but no reply yet. Patience needed perhaps. I'll perhaps try SU too. Thanks

Comment: I re-ran the installation using the Guest account and it passes this hurdle. Stage 1 completes. As @abarnert said, it must be something in my env...

Comment: FYI, the python build tests for being built on a case-insensitive file system, like the default HFS+ OS X file systems, and builds the python executable with that amusing extension to avoid the conflict with the existing `Python` directory in the source directory.  On case-sensitive HFS+ systems, the executable is just plain `python`.

Comment: `Distutils/sysconfig.py` is part of the Python standard library. It's being called from `build_ext` which is used to build a C or C++ extension module, either during the interpreter build itself or later to install a third-party module. `get_config_vars` is used by it and elsewhere to search the Python Makefile for configuration variables defined during `./configure` processing.  `CXXFLAGS` is normally not set or needed during the build of Python itself, as it does not have any c++ components.  But I'm not familiar at all with Prefix or what customizations the Gentoo project has made.